# If $2 |3-x| + 5 = k$ has 2 $\mathbb{R}$ solutions for $x$, what are the possible values for $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

We have $2 |3-x| + 5 = k$, where $k$ is a constant. Provided this equation has two real solutions for $x$, what is the range of possible values for $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to $|3-x|=\frac{k-5}2$ which will have two real roots if $\frac{k-5}2>0\iff k>5$.

Comment: Why does $\frac{k-5}2$ have to be $> 0$ for $x$ to have two real solutions? Also, my textbook has $k \leq 11$ as a further condition.

Comment: $|y|=a\iff y=a\vee y=-a$, so it will have $2$ real roots iff $a>0$.

Comment: The other answers were longer but I'm picking this as the best answer because you explained the logic behind it in your comment. Thanks

Comment: but first I think there was a mistake in the term in the modulus... I sent you an edit

Comment: Oh... OK, actually you have $|y|=|-y|$.

Answer (score 3):

$2|3-x|+5$ has a minimum at $x=3$ and is $\text V$ shaped above it. Hence, $k>5.$

[image]

Comment: very nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle\frac{k-5}2=|3-x|\ge0\iff k-5\ge0\iff k\ge5$

If $\displaystyle k=5,|x-3|=0\iff x=3$ for real $x$

So, $\displaystyle k>5$

Comment: oops I just edited the question to correct a mistake about what's in the modulus sign

Comment: @hb2 Same line of reasoning holds though...

Comment: @hb20007, For real $x,|x|=+x$  if $x\ge0$ and $|x|=-x$ for $x<0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee My textbook also has $k \leq 11$ as a further condition?

Comment: @hb20007, Counter example, $k=13\implies |3-x|=4\implies 3-x=\pm4\implies x=?$

Comment: I only understood it from Jlam's comment so here's +1 instead

Answer (score 1):

We have $ \displaystyle\frac{k-5}2=|3-x|\ge0\Rightarrow k-5\ge0\Rightarrow k\ge5$

1. If $\displaystyle k=5 $  we have $|x-3|=0\Rightarrow x=3$ for real $x$
2. If $k>5$ we have $\displaystyle|x-3|=\frac{k-5}2\Rightarrow-\frac{k-5}2-3=x\vee x=\frac{k-5}2+3$

Since you requested we have two (real) roots, we must have $\displaystyle k>5$.

NB. Your edit that we should have $k\leq11$ somehow is not something that follows from the equation you've given us...